# Sweet Alert Confirm before Deleting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

- I have a data table containing announcements,The delete button works fine but it deletes the announcement without getting the response from the script(Sweet Alert). I hope someone can help

---

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('deleteannun').onclick = function()
{
  swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to recover this announcement!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
     return true;
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your announcement is safe", "error");
    return false;
  }
});
}
</script>
```

```html
//Connection here
$sql = "SELECT annun_ID, annun_title, annun_author, annun_date, annun_details FROM annun order by annun_ID DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<tr><td id=\"titleannun\">". $row["annun_title"]. "</td><td>". $row["annun_author"]. " </td><td>" . $row["annun_date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["annun_details"] ."</td>
 <td>
 <a href='includes/deleteannun.php?title=".$row["annun_title"]."'class=\"btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs\" ><i class=\"fa fa-trash\" id=\"deleteannun\"></i></a>";
  }
} else {
}
```

Comment: You should output php with `<?php echo $row['Annun_ID']; ?>` not as is.. also you may want to fire this event in order to happen: `$('form').submit(warni);`

Comment: Hello @ToniMichelCaubet I edited the question, can you help me?

Comment: hello @dsfq can you help me?

Comment: Try like this `document.getElementById('deleteannun').onclick = function(e) {  e.preventDefault(); /*the rest of your code*/`

Comment: You can provide me with a test link?

Comment: It works now but with some complications, the `No please` button works fine but the `yes delete it` doesn't work or go to the delete php file

Comment: I see, that you output the a with the id=deleteannun in a while-loop. ID's should be unique, better use a class.